# Rolling sum of time series with factor

Tags: r, filter, time-series

I am trying to calculate a rolling sum for a time series of returns `r` ranging over T dates. However at each date t when I calculate the rolling sum, I want to factor in a weight `w` for each number in the rolling sum.

The formula would be for every date t:

```
[Sum from i=1 to m](w(i)*r(t-i-1))
```

Lets look at a very simple example. I have a return series of T=6 returns `r`. For each date `t` I want to calculate the rolling sum over the last two dates (m=2). I also want to weight the first observation twice as much as the second.

```
r <- c(100,110,100,110,100,110)                 
w <- c(1,0.5)
```

I know that I can easily do the rolling sum using the filter function:

```
filter(r, rep(1, 2))
```

However I am not able to include the weight factor into the rolling sum. The following line gives the wrong result of `c(155, 155, 155, 155, 155,  NA)`

```
filter(r*w, rep(1, 2))
```

where I would really like to have the result `c(155, 160, 155, 160, 155, NA)`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
filter(r, rev(w))
# [1] 155 160 155 160 155  NA
```

An important information about the argument `filter` from the help page of `?filter`:

> filter
>   a vector of filter coefficients in **reverse** time order (as for AR or MA coefficients).

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: "a vector of filter coefficients in reverse time order". Excuse my ignorance; but _why_?

Answer (score 1):

`rollapply` in the [zoo package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) can do that:

```
> rollapply(r, 2, crossprod, w, fill = NA)
[1] 155 160 155 160 155  NA
```